# jquery reorder on load and resize

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the following code to reorder my two divs to work on both resize and and load. Right now it only works on resizing.

I know I'm missing something simple most likely. Thank you for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));

    function listenWidth( e ) {
        if($(window).width()<640)
        {
            $("#context").remove().insertAfter($("#content"));
        } else {
            $("#context").remove().insertBefore($("#content"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for using: `$("#context").remove().insertAfter($("#content"));` ???  Ok i see, i misread `context` and `content` thinking it was same element ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind both events:

```
$(window).on("load resize", listenWidth);
```

Or still use `bind()`:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", listenWidth);
```

Comment: thanks. I used your first suggestion and it worked perfectly.